# Rails uninitialized constant error in command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I'm using Rails 4. I created a db migration. Called `AddPlaceidToUserid`:

```
class AddPlaceidToUserid < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :subscriptions do |t|
      t.integer :placeid
      t.integer :userid
    end
  end
end
```

After migration with `rake db:migrate` it creates a table in my database, but in rails console when I show all tables it shows me `["schema_migrations", "places", "subscriptions"]`, but when I try to show `Subscriptions` table console writes me an error:

```
2.0.0p353 :004 > Subscription.all
  NameError: uninitialized constant Subscription
    from (irb):4
    from /home/alexefremo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/alexefremo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/alexefremo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

In `PlacesController` `Subscription.all` of course causes the same error. I missed something, except creating migration?

Comment: have you created the model? 
you need to initialize the `Subscription` model somewhere in your code

most propably on `app/models/subscription.rb`

Comment: @xlembouras it worked great. thanks. i'm a bit newbie, so it'll be alesson for me

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html is your friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to generate a model:

```
rails g model Subscription place_id:integer user_id:integer
```

That will create a model `Subscription` and also a database migration for it.